# Field not saving via form load rule?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, office-365, custom-form, infopath-rules

I have a form that has a people field on it (Username) and a multi-person people field on it (Editors).  A form load rule populates the Username field with the current user and another rules uses a data connection to pull a list of people into the Editors field.

This works fine on a 'new' form, I can see the data being populated on screen.  However when I submit the form, the data is no longer stored in the fields (doesn't show in list view)?

This isn't a major problem as I only need the data when someone edits the form to do a few checks, however when the saved form is subsequently edited, the form load rules don't appear to be populating the fields anymore?

Anyone know why this might be??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, something with the people fields was causing this, I've resorted to text fields and it's working fine now.